# Cannot connect to mongodb localhost after macOS upgrade to Ventura 13.5.1/mongodb v7

Tags: mongodb, macos

I just upgraded to 13.5.1 and homebrew updated mongodb-community, and while it seems the mongod service is running, I cannot establish a connection to it. Here is what I'm seeing.

When I restart the server I receive this:

```
brew services restart mongodb-community 
Stopping
`mongodb-community`... (might take a while)
==    Successfully stopped `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
==    Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
```

When I try to make a connection, this one using mongosh, I receive this error,

```
Current Mongosh Log ID: 64e1b482dcd21cd87606e66d
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.10.5
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

The log file contains this message but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-20T08:40:04.690+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-20T08:40:04.705+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-08-20T08:40:04.712+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20573,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Wrong mongod version","attr":{"error":"UPGRADE PROBLEM: Found an invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document (ERROR: Location4926900: Invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document in admin.system.version: { _id: \"featureCompatibilityVersion\", version: \"5.0\" }. See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/6.0-compatibility/#feature-compatibility. :: caused by :: Invalid feature compatibility version value '5.0'; expected '6.0' or '6.3' or '7.0'. See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/6.0-compatibility/#feature-compatibility.). If the current featureCompatibilityVersion is below 6.0, see the documentation on upgrading at https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/6.0/#upgrade-procedures."}}
```

I'm running mongodb v7.

```
db version v7.0.0

Build Info: {
    "version": "7.0.0",
    "gitVersion": "37d84072b5c5b9fd723db5fa133fb202ad2317f1",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "system",
    "environment": {
        "distarch": "aarch64",
        "target_arch": "aarch64"
    }
}
```

Comment: Review the config file, the  upgrade may reverted them to default.

Comment: @jQueeny How do you know whether config file `/etc/mongod.conf` is used?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear and it even gives detailed description how to solve it:

```
UPGRADE PROBLEM: Found an invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document
(
    ERROR: Location4926900: Invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document in admin.system.version: 
    { _id: \"featureCompatibilityVersion\", version: \"5.0\" }. 
    See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/6.0-compatibility/#feature-compatibility.    
    :: caused by :: 
    Invalid feature compatibility version value '5.0'; expected '6.0' or '6.3' or '7.0'. 
    See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/6.0-compatibility/#feature-compatibility.
).  
If the current featureCompatibilityVersion is below 6.0, see the
documentation on upgrading at https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/6.0/#upgrade-procedures.
```

What else do you need to know?

Before you upgrade to version 7.0, you must upgrade to version 6.x

Comment: I was already at 6.x prior to the upgrade. So what I need to know is how to update the featureCompatibilityVersion when I can't connect to the server. The documentation seems to indicate I have to connect to the admin db. But my connections are being refused.

Comment: Did you follow the documentation for the upgrade? Most likely not, you forgot to set the featureCompatibilityVersion

Comment: I didn't upgrade mongodb specifically, I ran a brew update and it was included. So back to my question. Is there a method that I can resolve this problem? I've uninstalled and reinstalled using brew install mongoldb-community, but the issue remains. Any direction you can provide is much appreciated.

Comment: Install version 6 and set `{featureCompatibilityVersion: 6}`. Then you can install version 7